# Prove that a homoegenous polynomial on $K^{n+1}$ of degree $ d<|K|$, vanishes at $|K|$ points on the line $\mathbb{P}^1 \subset \mathbb{P}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, plane-geometry

Prove that a homoegenous polynomial on $K^{n+1}$ of degree  $ d<|K|$, vanishes at $|K|$ points oth the line $\mathbb{P}^1 \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ then vanishes on $\mathbb{P}^1$.

Very much struggling with this problem I believe it is meant to be analogous to
polynomial to the proof
a non zero Polynomial on $K^{n}$ of degree  $ d<|K|$, vanishes at more than $d$ points on the line $L$, $a +tv$ then it vanishes on the line.

Really would appreciate the help or some hints.

Comment: Hint: look at the degree. Do you know any theorems about degrees and projective space?

Comment: Can we describe the plane as a degree 1 polynimal. Then use Bezout's identity

Comment: You may find the Bezout theorem version for projective space more convenient to argue.

Comment: I will still need to know if, I can desrcibe $\mathbb{P}^1$, as a degree 1 polynomial. I don't believe this is true.
However, I am tryinn g another proof. 
The affine hyper plane, $K^n$ can be desrcibed as the solutions to the degree 1 polynomial, $F=a_1x_1+a_2x_2+...+a_nx_n +d$. The any ojne dimensional plane will be contained in a hyperspace.
Then we can just appply Bezouts identity.